# why nl2br() is adding an extra <br>?

Tags: wpdb

I store the text with `wpdb->insert`. While retrieving it with `wpdb->get_results` I `echo` it with `nl2br()` function to preserve the new lines (or it will be echoed without line breks).

Problem is that `nl2br` is adding one extra `<br>` on each `<br>` set in the text.

Example:

if text in the db is stored like this:

```
test

test
```

i'll get this

```
test
<br>
<br>
test
```

instead of this, as i expect

```
test
<br>
test
```

am i doing something wrong?

I also tried `echo wpautop($text, true)`: as per documentation, with the true value, it should return `<br>` instead of `<p>`, but it is still returning `<p>`.

What's the correct way to echo the data retrieved from the db preserving the correct number of line breaks?

Comment: You have two new-line characters in your string, `test\n\ntest`, so therefore you got two `<br>` from `nl2br()`. It looks normal to me.

Comment: @birgire so you are telling to me that it is not possible to write 2 line separated by just one line but minimum two? or you know any other system?